# Count number of times an incident appears on different dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an incident with multiple rows (with multiple software products impacted on different rows), and also the same ID is linked with multiple dates

| Inc ID | S/W prod | Date Raised |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Inc1 | Prod1 | 02/02/2023 |
| Inc2 | Prod2 | 03/04/2023 |
| Inc1 | Prod3 | 04/06/2023 |
| Inc3 | Prod4 | 05/05/2023 |
| Inc2 | Prod5 | 05/05/2023 |
| Inc2 | Prod6 | 05/05/2023 |
| Inc1 | Prod7 | 17/07/2023 |
| Inc1 | Prod8 | 28/10/2023 |

I need help on creating a field with the formula to calculate the count of incidents occuring on different dates (not on the basis of rows). I cant use count because it will count the incidents on the basis of the number of rows, but i want the incidents occuring on the basis of dates. How can i get the same? Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: This is not a script writing site. Show what you've tried so far, and you could get help here.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have tried, **and also** the output you would expect from your posted data. Depending on your desired output, you should be able to do this with a combination of the `UNIQUE` and `FILTER` functions.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - I understand it isnt. But was stuck hence asked for help since i am a beginner. Wanted some workaround and fortunately the answer response helped me. Anyway thanks to you too for your help. Have a good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you try Excel Power Query.

[image]

Load the table to Power Query > click Transform tab > select Group By button in Table group.

Select Advanced > Set Inc ID column and Date Raised as the basis for grouping.

Select Count Rows as the Operation.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this is restricted in my company but i found a workaround of creating a pivot table with each inc and dates, and then running the query -QUERY('Dynamic Table'!1:100, "select A, sum (C) where A is not NULL group by A" where A was the Inc ID and C is the unique count of each Inc for each date. Hence it worked but i am still trying to find a short route to get this solution.